# Linq throwing Object reference not set to an instance of an object error

Tags: c#, linq

I started getting into learning how to use linq and I have followed some examples, then went off on my own. But when I run the app, I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", and I am not sure why, everything looks ok, but since I'm starting to learn how to use Linq, maybe someone will know why it throws that error

here is my code..

```
DataSet ds = GetContacts();

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

        var query = from contact in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where contact.Field<string>("ContactName").Contains("aria")
                    select contact;

        foreach (var con in query)
            Response.Write(con.Field<string>("ContactName") + "<br>");
```

**EDIT ADDED Code for GetContacts**

```
public DataSet GetContacts()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        string strCm = "select * from [Contacts]";
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(strCm, cn);
        cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
        cn.Open();
        da.Fill(ds);
        cn.Close();

        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: Look on the sidebar on the right. I see your error several times at a glance, so this is likely a duplicate.

Comment: What line is throwing the exception? Make sure `ds` isn't null.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange,  contact.Field<string>("ContactName").Contains("aria") that's where the error is being thrown

Comment: can you post the code for GetContacts();

Comment: are you sure you have a column named `ContactName` ?

Comment: I added the GetContacts method and I am using NorthWind as a test

Comment: @Selman22, yes I am sure.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange, I stepped through the code and dataset is being populated

Comment: @Magus, Just because the question seems like a duplicate, doesn't always mean that its the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, well, I'm quite certain that one of the 500 duplicates is the same issue. This is a common, well documented error that only really has one cause.

Comment: @Magus, I am sure that is common, and since I have asked this question I have looked around on here and not finding anything specific to what my issue is. Maybe I am searching for the wrong phrases or keywords? But if you have something positive or direction to contribute instead of being all "Boooooo user2970223"? and claiming that it is "likely" a duplicate, it would have been more productive if you can point to some reference to how it is a duplicate.

Comment: Have you bothered reading any of the ones on the side here, the one's automatically linked because of their similarity? Have you thought about the text of the exception? Some variable, clearly, is not set. Have you tried debugging to find out which it is? I'm not here to make fun of you or put you down, but I simply cannot accept that you are having a fully unique issue with Linq and this exception. I honestly believe you *could* have found out by now. Asking a question is slower, and a question like this is unlikely to be answered, since it has been so thoroughly elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I have actually. But if I don't see code that is similar to what I wrote then I tend to look at it as it won't help, that is due to the fact that I don't really understand what is being explained, because I can't correlate the two. I've always used ADO and writing stored procedures and all that, but I have been using Linq to Sql, for some reason I understand that. Point is that I am having a hard time understanding Linq to Dataset. I have stepped through the code and the dataset and table and the query and the foreach and everything is there, it gets to a point where there error pops up

Comment: Are the some of the values in "ContactName" column are null? As I saw this code : contact.Field<string>("ContactName")

Comment: @PandaZhang, I don't think so, it should only have 3 values. I did it with Linq to Entities, slightly different from the above code, and it showed 3 records. I'm using NorthWind database for this, I've checked through the dataset and table and there are no nulls.

Comment: The biggest problem with this answer is that you already know what's wrong: Something is null. We can't tell you what it is, because we don't have your db configuration and entire program. We, and related answers, have explained that you should try debugging. We did this because only you can find this problem. Maybe some of your data is coming back null. If you went to a doctor and said that your arm hurts, you won't simply get a prescription. You'll have to explain which arm, when, when it began, and what makes it worse. The doctor is not inside of you, so he can only wait for your answer.